# Como puedo encontrar los valores diferentes por categoria en un dataframe?

Tags: python, r

amigos, espero se encuentren muy bien. He estado tratando de crear código que me permita encontrar las categórias de un DF que tenga valores distintos y cuales no tengan, pero no sé como puedo hacer para recorrer un DF por categorías. Trate hacer un distint y agrupar pero esto no me funcionó. Mi df es así:

```
Nombres     códigos 
Meta           1 
Meta           1
Berlin         2
Berlin         2
Quito          3
Quito1         3
Valencia       4
Valencia      45
```

Lo primero que quiero hacer es agrupar por la variable nombres y mirar cual tiene códigos diferentes como por ejemplo la categoría valencia que tiene dos códigos distintos asociados.
Lo segundo es agrupar por códigos y mirar que la categoría tiene nombres diferentes asociados, por ejemplo la caregoria 3 tiene los nombres diferentes asociados quito y quito1

A continución anexo las formas que he intentado, pero no me han dado ningun resultado. lo he intentado tanto en R como en python.

**usando dplyr**

```
agrupando_1 <- 
df %>%                             
group_by(Nombres) %>%
summarise(unique_codes = n_distinct(Codigos))
```

**usando data.table**

```
library(data.table)
group_2 <- 
data.table(df)[ , .(unique_Codigos = length(unique(Codigos))), 
by = Nombres]
group_2
```

**python pandas**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("nombres_codigos.xlsx")

df2 = df.groupby(['Nombres'])['Nombres'].count()
df2
```

Comment: Buen día, para entender un poco mejor, ¿Deseas obtener las filas que tengan diferentes códigos para un mismo nombre y diferentes nombres para un mismo código? o ¿Solo quieres obtener los nombres con diferentes códigos y los códigos con diferentes nombres? Es decir, ¿Deseas obtener la fila completa o únicamente el valor de la celda nombres y códigos que tengan más de un elemento asociado?

Comment: O ¿Deseas obtener el número de códigos asociados a cada nombre y el número de nombres asociados a cada código? o ¿Una lista de asociaciones? Yo creo que lo más fácil es que edites tu pregunta y agregues un ejemplo del resultado esperado para que sea más fácil darte una respuesta que se aplique a tus necesidades

Comment: @HeytalePazguato deseo obtener el número de códigos asociados a cada categoría nombre y el número de nombres asociados a cada código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré una forma de hacerlo con data.table en R.

lo primero que hice fue convertir el df en formato data.table

```
df_prueba=data.table(df)
```

luego conté cuantas veces se repetía cada nombre en el df_prueba

```
df_prueba_nombre = df_prueba[, .N, by = Nombre]
setnames(df_prueba_nombre ,"N", "Frec")
```

posteriormente hago lo mismo pero para contar los codigos

```
df_prueba_codigo = df_prueba[, .N, by = Cogdigo]
setnames(df_prueba_codigo ,"N", "Frec")
```

lugo hago un leftjoin donde uno el df_prueba_codigo con el df_prueba, para que se le agreguen los nombres a cada codigo con su frecuencia.

```
setkey(df_prueba_codigo,Codigo)
setkey(df_prueba,Codigo)

lj_prueba <- merge(df_prueba_codigo,df_prueba, all.x=TRUE)
```

luego aplico un unique porque los nombres con la frecuencia quedaron duplicados al aplicar el join.

```
lj_prueba =unique(lj_prueba , incomparables = FALSE, fromLast = FALSE,
        nmax = NA,)
```

ahora voy a hacer un leftjoin para unir el df lj_prueba con el df que contiene la frecuencia de repeticion de los nombres df_prueba_nombre.

```
setkey(df_prueba_nombre,Nombre)
setkey(lj_prueba,Nombre)

# perform the join using the merge function
f_prueba <- merge(lj_prueba,df_prueba_nombre, all.x=TRUE)
```

por ultimo creo una nueva columna en el df y establesco un condicional que me diga yes si la frecuencia del código coincide con la frecuencia del nombre y que me diga no si no coinciden para así encontrar las variables repetidas que tienen nombre o codigo diferente.

```
f_prueba$igual = ifelse(f_prueba$Frec.x==f_prueba$Frec.y,"Yes","No")
```

esto será una nueva columna del `df f_prueba`

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Una forma fácil de obtener los resultados que buscas es utilizando [`pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) junto con [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) y luego [`pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html)

Utilizando tu `dataframe` como referencia puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
nombres = df.drop_duplicates().groupby(['Nombres'])['códigos'].count()
codigos = df.drop_duplicates().groupby(['códigos'])['Nombres'].count()
```

Al imprimir `nombres` y `codigos` obtenemos:

```
Nombres
Berlin      1
Meta        1
Quito       1
Quito1      1
Valencia    2
Name: códigos, dtype: int64

códigos
1     1
2     1
3     2
4     1
45    1
Name: Nombres, dtype: int64
```

Y si lo quieres ver con el nombre de la columna podrías utilizar [`pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html)

```
nombres = df.drop_duplicates().groupby(['Nombres']).agg({'códigos': 'count'})
codigos = df.drop_duplicates().groupby(['códigos']).agg({'Nombres': 'count'})
```

Al imprimir `nombres` y `codigos` obtenemos:

```
          códigos
Nombres          
Berlin          1
Meta            1
Quito           1
Quito1          1
Valencia        2

         Nombres
códigos         
1              1
2              1
3              2
4              1
45             1
```